# Want to remove the do while inside do while loop

Tags: c#

I want to remove nested do-while loop from my code.
I used these nested do-while for reentering the value if it is not valid, I am validating values inside Employee class.
I am new in c# so please help me to reduce this code.

FirstName, LastName are properties.

I Copied the nested do-while into a method and send employeeDetails.FirstName and employeeDetails.LastName as the parameter of the method but it is not working because FirstName and LastName are the property of the class.

here is my Entry Class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Employee_Details
{
    class EntryClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strChoice;
            List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
            do
            {
                Employee employeeDetails = new Employee();

                bool exception=false;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter first name");
                    try
                    {
                        employeeDetails.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
                        exception = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        exception = true;
                    }
                } while (exception);

                exception = false;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("enter last name");
                    try
                    {
                        employeeDetails.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
                        exception = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        exception = true;
                    }
                } while (exception);

                exception = false;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("enter date of birth in dd/MM/yyyy ");
                    try
                    {
                        employeeDetails.SetDOB(Console.ReadLine());
                        exception = false;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        exception = true;
                    }
                } while (exception);
                employeeList.Add(employeeDetails);
                Console.WriteLine("Do You want to continue?");
                strChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            } while (strChoice == "yes");

            var query = from employeeDetails in employeeList
                        select new
                        {
                            firstName = employeeDetails.FirstName,
                            lastName = employeeDetails.LastName,
                            dob = employeeDetails.DateOfBirth.ToString("d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture),
                            age=employeeDetails.GetAge()
                      };
            foreach (var employee in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{employee.firstName},{employee.lastName},{employee.dob},{employee.age}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Entry class looks like this.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Employee_Details
    {
        class Employee
        {
            private string first_name;
            private string last_name;
            private DateTime date_of_birth;

            public DateTime DateOfBirth => date_of_birth;

            public void SetDOB(string dob)
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dob, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime returnDate))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Date");
                }
                else if (GetAge() <= 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Birth Year shoud not be greater then current year");
                }
                date_of_birth= returnDate;
            }

            public string LastName
            {
                set
                {
                    last_name = CheckString(value);
                }
                get
                {
                    return last_name;
                }
            }

            public string FirstName
            {
                set
                {
                    first_name = CheckString(value);
                }
                get
                {
                    return first_name;
                }
            }

            private string CheckString(string value)
            {
                string returnString = "";
                var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)^[a-z.,\s]+$");
                bool res = regex.IsMatch(value);
                if (res)
                {
                    returnString = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid String");
                }
                return returnString;
            }

            public int GetAge()
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
                int age = now.Year - date_of_birth.Year;
                return age;
            }
        }
    }
```

FirstName, LastName, and DateOfBirth will throw an exception when we give any invalid data.

Comment: How would `Console.ReadLine()` throw an exception?

Comment: @gunr2171, text longer than Int32 is one.

Comment: @DragandDrop somehow I doubt that this program needs to take care of that edge case.

Comment: I am validating data if first name contains digit then the property should throw an exception.

Comment: @ManishTiwari that's not what your code is doing, nor have you said anything in your requirements about any sort of validation.

Comment: Don´t overcomplicate your program by those unlike edgecases. You may simply Omit the try-catch. Nevertheless `ReadLine` doesn´t throw an exception if anyone enters numbers as input. You have to check, e.g. by using a regex.

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of catching exceptions. Apart from that your program is ok. Some minor things ofc, f.e. why do you use the exception-loop on properties that never throw an exception like `FirstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I edited the question. Can you help me now?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I am new in StackOverflow and in c#.I edited the question can you help me now?

Comment: @TimSchmelter check the code now I included my both classes.

Comment: I suppose you *will* need a nested loop as you´re reading two independent things: the current instance of `Employee` and if user wants to enter more instances. So the answer to your question is basically: it´s not possible to omit the nested loop.

Comment: @HimBromBeere so it is the best approach to do these kinds of questions.

Comment: If code work, it could be eligible for review..

Comment: this code works perfectly @DragandDrop so basically my question is to remove nested do-while and use some kind of method.

Comment: My understanding, exceptions are for exceptional circumstances. So improper user input is to be expected therefore isn't an exceptional circumstance. You should use simple validation techniques for validating input, not exceptions. If validation fails, writeline a message expaling the error and give them the chance to try again until they get it correct.

Comment: I used if else inside Employee class but my instructor told me to remove all the code from Employee class, here code means Console.Write() and Console.Read() from Employee class.  @AnthonyVoelker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of catching exceptions. Some things you could improve, f.e. why do you use the exception-loop on properties that never throw an exception like reading the `FirstName` and `LastName` from the console?

One way to make it more readable would be to define `Func` delegates:

```
Func<bool> askContinue = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do You want to continue?");
    return Console.ReadLine().Trim().Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
};
Func<string> askFirstName = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first name");
    return Console.ReadLine().Trim();
};
Func<string> askLastName = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter last name");
    return Console.ReadLine().Trim();
};
Func<DateTime?> askDateOfBirth = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter date of birth(dd/MM/yyyy)");
    string dobStr = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    DateTime dob;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dobStr, out dob))
        return dob;
    return null;
};
```

Now the loop itself is reduced to the essential and readable:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
bool addEmployee = true;

while (addEmployee)
{
    var emp = new Employee
    {
        FirstName = askFirstName(),
        LastName = askLastName()
    };
    DateTime? dob = askDateOfBirth();
    while (!dob.HasValue)
        dob = askDateOfBirth();
    emp.DateOfBirth = dob.Value;

    employeeList.Add(emp);
    addEmployee = askContinue();
}
```

Comment: this solution is very high level for me.but I think this should work.

Comment: @ManishTiwari: instead of using `Func` you could also use normal methods or encapsulate it in other classes(f.e. `EmployeeReader`). I just wanted to give you an idea how to reduce the loop to the essential.

Comment: @ManishTiwari, It's the power of So. Even if it's "high level" but as it's readable and clear. You can reuse it and modify it at will. The idea is to use the second code block of Tim's answer as caneva for the main code you wanted to reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that returns a name so:

```
private static string GetName(string question)
{
    string name = null;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        try
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            name = null;
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name));

    return name;
}
```

And then in your program you can set your do while:

```
do {
    var employeeDetails = new Employee
    {
        FirstName = GetName("Enter firstname and press enter."),
        LastName = GetName("Enter firstname and press enter."),
    };

    employeeList.Add(employeeDetails);
    Console.WriteLine("Do You want to continue?");
    strChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
} while (strChoice == "yes");
```

Now add the DOBgetter and there you go, you've reduced nesting succesfully.